# vimrc - Acess Denied

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, vimrc

I'm trying to add in

```
colorscheme desert
```

at the bottom of my _vimrc file within Windows 7 and when trying to save it, I keep getting "Access Denied". I set my HOME variable to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim" but still no luck.

Comment: Hmm...I figured it out. I just had to add special permissions to my user group.

Answer (score 3):

Don't save your user preferences in Program Files, save them in your $HOME directory, which should be set to C:\Users\username (or similar).

Comment: +1 and especially don't set your HOME variable to C:\Program Files\anything.

Answer (score 0):

To [run a program as administrator hold down Ctrl + Shift](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html) when you open it. This might give you the permissions to do what you want to do.

Comment: thx for the tip, but the option isn't available for the file itself and when opening it from Vim (under admin) still didn't have any luck.